# Add Space After Special Character In A Text File

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need help separating multiple if statements in a file.

Change:

```
 [[ "$File1" == "Word1" ]] || [[ "$File1" == "Word2" ]] ||
```

to:

```
 [[ "$File1" == "Word1" ]] ||
 [[ "$File1" == "Word2" ]] ||
```

Everything I've found online does not work with special characters like ||
I think I need to use awk or sed, but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's@|| @||\n@g' input
[[ "$File1" == "Word1" ]] ||
[[ "$File1" == "Word2" ]] ||
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/\|\| /,"&"RS)}1' file

echo "[[ "$File1" == "Word1" ]] || [[ "$File1" == "Word2" ]] ||" | awk '{sub(/\|\| /,"&"RS)}1'
[[  == Word1 ]] ||
[[  == Word2 ]] ||
```